# Crash KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED

Tags: swift, crash, key-value-observing

I'm seeing crashes in my crash log, but I have yet to experience a crash directly. I've searched everything and tried everything but I'm stuck.

Any ideas on why I'm getting these in my crash logs?

**Crash log**

```
CrashReporter Key:   d42015aa3717735a5388beca859904bc83c7d8a1
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,2
Process:             Waterspeed [9082]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/60208DDD-0A10-41FE-B309-56CF3CCB0E45/Waterspeed.app/Waterspeed
Identifier:          TNT.Waterspeed
Version:             23 (2.9.28)
AppStoreTools:       10G3
AppVariant:          1:iPhone9,2:12.2
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           TNT.Waterspeed [2182]


Date/Time:           2019-07-22 19:20:09.0959 -1000
Launch Time:         2019-07-21 23:14:01.7633 -1000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.3.1 (16F203)
Baseband Version:    5.60.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000fbcae9b80
VM Region Info: 0xfbcae9b80 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 56315779969  
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO            0000000280000000-00000002a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  
      UNUSED SPACE AT END

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [9082]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001fdcf60e0 object_isClass + 16 (objc-runtime-new.h:976)
1   Foundation                      0x00000001ff56a8d0 KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED + 64 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1122)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001ff568170 NSKeyValueWillChangeWithPerThreadPendingNotifications.llvm.9306004367141260615 + 304 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1152)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001ff4e1d44 -[NSProgress _setValueForKeys:settingBlock:] + 264 (NSProgress.m:773)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001ff4ff424 -[NSProgress _setRemoteValues:forKeys:] + 192 (NSProgress.m:2347)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ff6b3020 __45-[_NSProgressProxy _setRemoteValues:forKeys:]_block_invoke + 64 (NSProgressSubscriber.m:118)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaaee68 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20 (CFRunLoop.c:1838)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaae76c __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 272 (CFRunLoop.c:1879)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa9cd8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2312 (CFRunLoop.c:3178)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa90b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000200ca979c GSEventRunModal + 104 (GSEvent.c:2245)
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000022b457978 UIApplicationMain + 212 (UIApplication.m:4353)
12  Waterspeed                      0x0000000102d95068 main + 68 (LoginViewController.swift:34)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001fe56e8e0 start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6af0f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6ae5a0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaaea10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa9920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa90b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ff476fac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ff476e3c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000022b53d494 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:606)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001ff5a36a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984 (NSThread.m:1175)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c2c0 _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c220 _pthread_start + 44 (pthread.c:884)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcdc thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6bc920 write + 8
1   Waterspeed                      0x0000000102f50cb4 CLSSDKFileLog + 288 (CLSInternalLogging.c:0)
2   Waterspeed                      0x0000000102f48388 CLSMachExceptionServer + 912 (CLSMachException.c:249)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c2c0 _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c220 _pthread_start + 44 (pthread.c:884)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcdc thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6af0f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6ae5a0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaaea10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa9920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa90b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001ff0c274c -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 216 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1365)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ff5a36a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984 (NSThread.m:1175)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c2c0 _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c220 _pthread_start + 44 (pthread.c:884)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcdc thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6af0f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6ae5a0 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaaea10 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236 (CFRunLoop.c:2615)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa9920 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360 (CFRunLoop.c:2971)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feaa90b0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ff476fac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Waterspeed                      0x000000010301e8d0 -[_FSRRunLoopThread main] + 252 (FSRWebSocket.m:1843)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001ff5a36a4 __NSThread__start__ + 984 (NSThread.m:1175)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c2c0 _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c220 _pthread_start + 44 (pthread.c:884)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcdc thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6ba328 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001feab76f4 __CFSocketManager + 620 (CFSocket.c:2242)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c2c0 _pthread_body + 128 (pthread.c:857)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73c220 _pthread_start + 44 (pthread.c:884)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcdc thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6bb93c kevent_id + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe51bbf0 _dispatch_kq_poll + 332 (event_kevent.c:718)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe51b114 _dispatch_event_loop_poke$VARIANT$mp + 476 (event_kevent.c:1644)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001ff4fb080 -[NSFileAccessArbiterProxy revokeAccessClaimForID:] + 84 (NSFileAccessArbiter.m:2232)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001ff660af0 __98-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _withAccessArbiter:invokeAccessor:orDont:andRelinquishAccessCl... + 232 (NSFileCoordinator.m:960)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001ff660cc0 __85-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_i... + 28 (NSFileCoordinator.m:1014)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ff4e95a4 -[NSFileCoordinatorAccessorBlockCompletion decrement] + 76 (NSFileCoordinator.m:2245)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001ff4d8f48 -[NSFileCoordinator _invokeAccessor:thenCompletionHandler:] + 164 (NSFileCoordinator.m:470)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001ff65fbc0 __73-[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke + 88 (NSFileCoordinator.m:483)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001ff660c98 __85-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_i... + 108 (NSFileCoordinator.m:1013)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001ff4d9160 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _withAccessArbiter:invokeAccessor:orDont:andRelinquishAccessClaim:] + 452 (NSFileCoordinator.m:943)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001ff4da138 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 776 (NSFileCoordinator.m:1008)
12  Foundation                      0x00000001ff4d9e24 -[NSFileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] + 76 (NSFileCoordinator.m:480)
13  WatchConnectivity               0x0000000220177b1c -[WCContentIndex loadContentIfNecessary] + 808 (WCContentIndex.m:66)
14  Foundation                      0x00000001ff647ec4 __74-[NSFilePresenterXPCMessenger _makePresenter:observeChangeWithSubitemURL:]_block_invoke_2 + 48 (NSFileAccessArbiter.m:3360)
15  Foundation                      0x00000001ff66662c __95-[NSOperationQueue(NSFileCoordinationSupport) _fc_addUncancellableOperationForReactorID:block... + 140 (NSFileCoordinator.m:2427)
16  Foundation                      0x00000001ff581ef8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:1559)
17  Foundation                      0x00000001ff48e3e0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72 (NSOperation.m:1578)
18  Foundation                      0x00000001ff48d8c8 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740 (NSOperation.m:907)
19  Foundation                      0x00000001ff583c7c __NSOQSchedule_f + 272 (NSOperation.m:2165)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe55ca38 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1372)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe55d7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe502018 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2441)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe5016dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600 (queue.c:796)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe50e02c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372 (inline_internal.h:2482)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe50e8d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6072)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73d1b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464 (pthread.c:2361)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fe6b9f2c __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe735a84 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 92 (pthread_mutex.c:1228)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe7359f4 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow$VARIANT$mp + 272 (pthread_mutex.c:1304)
3   Foundation                      0x00000001ff478d44 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 64 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:68)
4   WatchConnectivity               0x00000002201650a0 -[WCSession onqueue_updateProgressForFileTransfer:progress:] + 280 (WCSession.m:517)
5   WatchConnectivity               0x0000000220164c9c __51-[WCSession onqueue_createProgressForFileTransfer:]_block_invoke_2 + 44 (WCSession.m:496)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001ff581ef8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16 (NSOperation.m:1559)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001ff48e3e0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72 (NSOperation.m:1578)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001ff48d8c8 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740 (NSOperation.m:907)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001ff583c7c __NSOQSchedule_f + 272 (NSOperation.m:2165)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe50b7f0 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104 (queue.c:518)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe55d7d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:511)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe502018 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2441)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe5016dc _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600 (queue.c:796)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe50e02c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372 (inline_internal.h:2482)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001fe50e8d0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128 (queue.c:6072)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73d1b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464 (pthread.c:2361)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001fe73fcd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000002833a9b60   x1: 0x000000016d0768d0   x2: 0x000000016d0768e0   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000003   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x00000002833b5320   x7: 0x000000023665c000
    x8: 0x0000000fbcae9b60   x9: 0x0000000000000008  x10: 0x00000001fea19e54  x11: 0x0000002a0000007f
   x12: 0x0000000104918f60  x13: 0x000001a238c5ba41  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000030000000302
   x16: 0x0000000238c5ba40  x17: 0x00000001fea19d00  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016d0768d0
   x20: 0x0000000000000003  x21: 0x000000022b98d9bf  x22: 0x00000002833a9b60  x23: 0x000000023665c000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000283d85bc0  x26: 0x0000000000000003  x27: 0x000000016d0768d0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016d0768c0   lr: 0x00000001ff56a8d0
    sp: 0x000000016d076890   pc: 0x00000001fdcf60e0 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Comment: I just encountered the same crash. I think it might be related to WatchConnectivity.
`Foundation                      0x00000001ff478d44 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 64 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:68)
4   WatchConnectivity               0x00000002201650a0 -[WCSession onqueue_updateProgressForFileTransfer:progress:] + 280 (WCSession.m:517)
5   WatchConnectivity               0x0000000220164c9c __51-[WCSession onqueue_createProgressForFileTransfer:]_block_invoke_2 + 44 (WCSession.m:496)`

Comment: Were you able to solve it?